# Howto pass extra param on SubGrid Jqgird

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net

Suppose the following grids

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#Clientes').jqGrid({colNames: ['Razón Social','Cuit','Dirección','Localidad','Teléfono','Tipo IVA','Mail','Saldo inicial','Facturar'], 
        colModel: [{ editable: true, editoptions: { "maxlength":70 }, editrules: { required: true }, name: 'RazonSocial' },
                   { editable: true, editoptions: { dataInit: CuitMask, "maxlength":13 }, editrules: { custom: true, custom_func: ValidateCuit, required: true }, name: 'NidentFiscal' },
                   { editable: true, editoptions: { "maxlength":70 }, editrules: { required: true }, name: 'Direccion' },
                   { editable: true, edittype: 'select', editoptions: { dataUrl: '/Ciudad/CmbCiudad' }, editrules: { required: true }, name: 'Ciudad' },
                   { editable: true, editoptions: { "maxlength":20 }, name: 'Telefono' }],
url: '/Clientes/List',
datatype: 'json',
mtype: 'POST',
pager: '#ClientesPager',
prmNames: { id: 'ClienteId' }, 
rowList: [10,15,20,25,30],
sortname: 'ClienteId',
subGrid: true,
subGridRowExpanded: function(subgridId, rowId) {
    var subgridTableId = subgridId + '_t';
    jQuery('#' + subgridId).append('<table id="' + subgridTableId + '"></table>');
    var subgridPagerId = subgridId + '_p';
    jQuery('#' + subgridId).append('<div id="' + subgridPagerId + '"></div>');
    $('#' + subgridTableId).jqGrid({colNames: ['Fecha','Importe'],
     colModel: [{ name: 'Fecha' },
                { editable: true, editrules: { number: true }, formatter: 'currency', formatoptions: { prefix: '$' }, name: 'Importe' }
               ],url: '/Honorarios/DetailSubgrid?id=' + rowId, datatype: 'json', mtype: 'POST', pager: '#' + subgridPagerId, 
     prmNames: { id: 'HonorarioId' }, 
     rowList: [10,15,20,25,30],
     sortname: 'HonorarioId',
     viewrecords: true,
     width: 600,
     height: '100%'}).jqGrid('navGrid', '#' + subgridPagerId,{ search: false },{ url: '/Honorarios/Update', closeAfterEdit: true },{ url: '/Honorarios/Update', closeAfterEdit: true },{ url: '/Honorarios/Delete' });
    },
viewrecords: true,
width: 1000,
height: '100%'
}).jqGrid('navGrid', '#ClientesPager',{ search: false },{ url: '/Clientes/Update', width: 500, closeAfterEdit: true }, { url: '/Clientes/Update', width: 500, closeAfterEdit: true }, { url: '/Clientes/Delete' });
});
```

I need to pass the ClienteId parameter when a record is added or edited in the sub grid
This should be done using postdata?
something like

```
 postData: {ClienteId: row_id}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution is using

```
editData: { ClienteId: rowId }
```

Tanks @tpeczek